# Is there a flexible way to clip a raster by a polygon either read from a shapefile or created with a set of vertex points?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, clip

I am trying to clip a raster (ascii or tif file) with polygons in python. The polygons can be read from a shapefile or created by a set of vertex points like `POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1 , 0 1, 0 0))`.

I know how to use `gdal.Warp` to clip a raster with the argument `cutlineDSName`, which represents a shapefile name.

But what if I want to use a simple polygon defined by a set of points to cut rasters?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be transforming your polygon `POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1 , 0 1, 0 0))` to geojson:

`{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]]]}`.

You can use an online converter like http://kostas.krevatas.net/wkt-convertor/

An then, set `cutlineDSName` to the polygon as a geojson file, for example `polygon.json`

...since geojson is a valid input format the same way as a shapefile is.